# login failed: target account name is invalid

Tags: file-sharing

We are in process of setting up disaster recovery site, have a bit of problem.

Right now we are replicating AD server to our DR site and rest of everything is duplicate setup.

**Issue that i am facing is, we have file share named //FileShare01/Folder1. We are using this fileshare to save roaming profiles. So from DR site as well it need to find this file share. So i tried putting in host file entry for 'FileShare01' to another server.**

**But i am getting 'login failed: target account name is invalid' with above setup when try to access that fileshare.**

Ping resolves the correct ip from host file entry. I am logged in as user which has rights to access folder. I can access folder using ip or servername. But not using host file entry.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're saying that you have another server (FileShare0x) and you're trying to make it answer as if it was FileShare01? If so, then you'll need to make a change to FileShare0x to make it listen on the alias FileShare01. The following is an excerpt from the MS KB article that explains the steps:

To resolve this problem in Windows Server 2003, follow these steps:

A. Start Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe)

B. Locate and click the following key in the registry:

C. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters

D. On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:

Value name: DisableStrictNameChecking

Data type: REG_DWORD

Radix: Decimal

Value: 1

E. Quit Registry Editor

F. Restart your computer

You may also have to set the SPN (Service Principal Name) for the Alias Name.

For example, you may have to enter a command that resembles the following commands:

setspn -a host/aliasname targetserver